# How to get values from all instances of key in JSON in Python

Tags: python

I have a response from a post request:

JSON RESPONSE :

> [
> {
> "a": 3,
> "b": 2,
> "c": 1,
> },
> {
> "a": 3,
> "b": 2,
> "c": 1
> }
> ]

How would I get the value from all instances of "c" and add it to an array? What I have now is:

```
all_C_Values= []

for entry in JSON_RESPONSE['c'].values()]
    print("Adding element:")
    print(element)
    all_C_Values.append(element)
```

This doesn't give me the answer I need though. Ideally the array would contain values [1,1].

If I loop through the response and try to append the value, I get:

> TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list

Comment: loop through it and get the values

Comment: `[x["c"] for x in xs]`

Comment: You should work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) if not done yet.

Comment: How would you do it if that data *didn't* come from a post request? If you can't answer that, then you should study the fundamentals before trying to do more complicated tasks - like anything involving a JSON API. Also, we call them *lists*.

Comment: Please fix the typos in the code attempt you show, and explain what result you get and how that is different from what you want. Then, if you can see the *pattern* in how the output is wrong, maybe you can think of a way to fix it?

Comment: Please also read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough. You have been on the site for years; you should know this stuff.

Comment: From reading the other comments, it seems that the *actual* problem you were experiencing is that you attempted to `json.loads` (i.e., use a library function to convert from string data to a parsed data structure) the already-parsed data. This is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) that nobody could reasonably have known you had from your description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because you cannot treat JSON as a dictionary yet, you must load it first

```
import json

response = json.loads(JSON_RESPONSE)
all_C_values = [dic['c'] for dic in response]
```

Comment: This works too. I just removed the json.loads() in my original fix, but this is the correct answer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
D = [ { "a": 3, "b": 2, "c": 1, }, { "a": 3, "b": 2, "c": 1 } ]
x = [x['c'] for x in D]
print(x)
```

Comment: That does not happen with the given code in isolation; and it also suggests that you are confused between the JSON text itself, and the parsed data structure. Whether or not you understand this properly, you would appear to have a new question that is better answered by a tutorial.

Comment: I do have a resolution for the issue. The resolution is for you to read and follow a tutorial, because a) that would solve the problem for you; b) the question you have asked does not meet the standards described in [ask] or any of the other links I gave you. The feedback I'm giving you not only is the most helpful possible, it's something you should already know because *you have learned many other programming languages before*. Learning Python is the same as learning any other programming language, and really the same as learning *anything*; there are fundamentals to study first.

Comment: Thank you. This will work if I remove the json.loads(JSON_RESPONSE).